# Can't save an ARCFOUR key in a KeyStore

Tags: java, cryptography

I generate an ARCFOUR key like this :

```
myKeyGenerator= KeyGenerator.getInstance("ARCFOUR");
myKeyGenerator.init(1024);
myKey = myKeyGenerator.generateKey();
```

and then I want to store it in my `KeyStore`with `myKeyStore.setKeyEntry(myKeyAlias, myKey, myPassword, null);` but it triggers the following error :

```
Key protection algorithm not found: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: unrecognized algorithm name: ARCFOUR
```

And I don't understand why as the "ARCFOUR" algorithm is supposed to be supported by my Java implementation (retrieved through the `Provider` list).

And, with the same code, I don't get any error if I use the "AES" algorithm.

I use PKCS #12 for my KeyStore.

Comment: Perhaps "RC4" or "RCFOUR" might work?  They are alternative names for the same algorithm.

Comment: Works for me. Your code is too incomplete to determine why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: What do you think could be missing?

Comment: `myKeyGenerator.init(1024);` what's the point of that? Many stream ciphers allow large keys, but generally a 128 bit key is all you need, especially for an old half (or more) broken algorithm like RC4.... Try a smaller key size with "RC4" as algorithm name.

Comment: If this is just to avoid the pitfall of using the initiail bits of the keystream and/or to include an IV, may I suggest a full key renewal or 256 bit key and skipping the stream forward by encrypting & discarding bits?

Comment: I don't especially want to encrypt my data with "ARCFOUR". I'm just trying to make an app able to make the most of each and every crypto algorithm my Java implementation furnishes. This problem is not restricted to "ARCFOUR" because I get the same error message with "Blowfish", "Chacha20" and "RC2" for instance, but not with "AES". And restricting the key size to 256 doesn't solve the problem.